# sendmail.cf to read server name from another file?

Tags: sendmail

I need to provide the name of a relay server to my sendmail configuration file.
This server name is however configurable via another system/application.

In case of a change, i need to change the server name in this file and restart sendmail.

Also, i dont have the option of compiling the sendmail.mc file everytime it changes.

**Is it possible to ask sendmail to read/include another file for the server name. This file will contain the name of the server which has been configured in the system?**

something like: include("./severname.conf");

where servername.conf will have the name of the server to which relaying needs to be done.

Is it possible?

Comment: I hope i have been able to post my query properly. In case its not clear please let me know, so that i may try to explain more on this requirement

Answer (score 1):

The smart host is macro `$S` so you need a sequence of commands like this:

```
cd /etc/mail
cp sendmail.cf sendmail.cf.old
sed -e 's/^DSold.host.name/DSnew.host.name/' sendmail.cf.old > sendmail.cf
```

and then restart sendmail.

Answer (score 1):

You may use default route in mailertable instead of smart host - see [FEATURE(mailertable)](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/mailertables.html). It will be consulted/used **before** smart host => it will override smart host.

mailertable file entry for default route ("single dot" as key):

```
.  relay:smart-host.example.net
```

Sendmail uses version of the file compiled using `makemap` program. No restart of `sendmail` daemon is needed after recompilation by `makemap`.

How to test it:

```
sendmail -C/etc/mail/sendmail-test.cf -d60.5 -bv recipient@example.net
```

`-C file` - use alternative configuration file
`-d60.5` - turn on tracking map lookups (including mailertable map)

Comment: Any operation that rebuilds a .db file via makemap does not require a sendmail restart (newaliases, virtusertable, mailertable, etc.)